# Selenium IDE Xpath vs Webdriver Xpath

Tags: html, selenium, webdriver

I'm newbie with Test Automation. When I locating element through Firepath with target:

```
 xpath=(//td[contains(@id, 'catProdTd_4723290')]/div/div[2]/h2)
```

Firefox founds that element and verify text.
But, when I trying to locate this element with Visual Studio 2012 and Selenium Web driver, I constantly have error: "Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[contains(@id, 'catProdTd_4723290')]/div/div[2]/h2"}" .

I tried escaping:

```
//td[@id=\"catProdTd_4723290\"]/div/div[2]/h2
```

but nothing. When I use isElementPresent method, it founds elements.
Is there some special method or rule that should be use when writing Xpath for WebDriver ?
I defined ISelenium variable, WebDriver... Clicks works, WaitForPageToLoad works, but this can not locate element.

```
IWebElement we= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(@id, 'catProdTd_4723290')]/div/div[2]/h2"));
```

HTML from page:

```
<td class="productItem" id="catProdTd_4723290"><div class="product-details">
    <div class="product-aside"> <img border="0" alt="Fork and Spoon Set" src="/_photos/store/glass-large.jpg" id="catlproduct_4723290">
     </div>
    <div class="product-main">
    <h2 class="product-name">Fork and Spoon Set</h2>
    <div class="price"><strong>$17.99</strong></div>
    <hr>

    <div class="attributes"></div>
    <hr>
    <div class="product-col-1">
    <div class="qty"> Quantity: <strong><input type="text" value="1" name="AddToCart_Amount" class="productTextInput" id="Units_4723290"></strong></div>
    <div class="stock">(N/A in-stock)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-col-2">
    <input type="submit" onclick="AddToCart(192951,4723290,'',4,'','',true);return false;" value="Buy Now" name="AddToCart_Submit" class="productSubmitInput">
    <div class="wish"><a href="/FavoriteProcess.aspx?OID=4723290&amp;OTYPE=27" class="favoritelink">Add to Wishlist</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-description">
    <h4>Product Information:</h4>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Aenean
    commodo ligula eget dolor.  Aenean massa.  Cum sociis natoque penatibus
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Main -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Product Details -->
</td>
```

I must add that I try to wait during debug and with

```
Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait
```

but nothing. This happens on other places also. I using Firefox for tests

Comment: Does that element become visible if something happens on the page? Does it take time to appear? What browser are you running against? Any IFrames? Please post the section of HTML that you are running it against.

Answer (score 2):

You are running into dynamic attributes.

My first recommendation to you.  [Switch to CSS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/&ei=Y1RAUpm4G8aayQGcuYDwDQ&usg=AFQjCNHgZqgCejFXEYn0OZopJiqxwJWlcA&sig2=1aP2NfPLDNnUDPeFjVKR2Q&bvm=bv.52434380,d.aWc).

My second recommendation, instead of boiling down into an entire parent-child hierarchy, why don't you just [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)!

So, lets look at your issue. You are trying to fetch the product name.  Easy.. we can use classes here.

```
css=td.productItem h2.product-name
```

*voila*, it was that easy to fetch.. instead of having this huge ugly xpath selector, we've simplified it to a css selector.

So onto the next problem, if we have multiple of `td.productItem`'s on the page, we can use a couple things.

Try,

```
css=td.productItem:nth-child(1) h2.productName
```

That will select the first `td` with class, `productItem`.

*note: you may need to specify the td's parent.. e.g. `css=div#container td.productItem:nth-child(1)`*

#### More specifics...

The reason your xpath is failing, is because of that `catProdTd_4723290` id assigned to the `<td>` element being generated automatically, rendering that element unselectable.  You can work around that, by doing `starts with`. for example, with css -

```
css=td[id^='catProdTd']
```

will select that `<td>`  take note though, that there might be more than 1 element selected.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer.  @garvan, if you want more info on selectors, the PDFs on this page have helped me greatly: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/

Comment: I tried CSS selectors (although I thought to work only with xpath) error: "Unable to locate element... " continues.
I tried to find elements on other site, that has no dynamic generated elements, and "Unable to locate element..." again.
This driving me crazy, in Firepath location is found, either by xpath or css, but when go through Visual Studio and WebDriver "FindElement" can not locate it ?!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using such a method for waiting:

```
 public bool boolWaitForElementIsDisplayed(By locator, int secondsToWait)
    {

        WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToWait));

        try
        {
            var FoundElement = Wait.Until<Boolean>(d =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return (d.FindElement(locator).Displayed && d.FindElement(locator).Enabled);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and then check as follows:

```
IWebElement h2Element = null;

string xpath = "//td[contains(@class,'productItem')]/div/div[contains(@class,'product-main')]/h2";
if (boolWaitForElementIsDisplayed(By.XPath(xpath), 30))
    h2Element = Driver.FindElement(xpath);
```

Answer (score -1):

So, the problem was that page isn't loaded. Why? Because `WebElement.Click()` not works. Why Click not working?! I don't know. 
I resolved problem with clicks using JavascriptExecutor:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)chauffeur;
IWebElement webel1 = chauffeur.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#nav ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) a[href='/products']"));
```

Instead of using

```
webel1.Click();
```

which not works, I used:

```
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", webel1);
```